# Access is denied error trying to run eclipse helios in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed Helios on my windows 7 64 bit laptop and started seeing this error after I tried to run some simple java code:

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\projects\workspace\Testing"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

I double checked my 32 bit installation on my desktop running WindowsXP and I have it setup the same way. What is odd is that it works for a while after I first install eclipse, then it throws the error after a while and I can't get past it. I did run java -version from the command line, so the java home is setup right.

If I remember right the widows preferences jre should point to this file, but why is the access denied error showing up?

**Aftermath:**
*Sorry for all this. Something got messed up in my environment, so I reverted back to a previous stable point and then I reinstalled eclipse which solved the problem.*

I did more checking and this is a common problem, but for differing causes. Here are some links that may help:

1. [Tutorial](http://jeffdickman.com/2010/07/installing-eclipse-64bit-on-windows-7-64bit/) for installing Eclipse with Windows 7
2. Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166795/eclipse-crushes-at-startup-exit-code-13) about crashes with Eclipse and Win7
3. Helios 64 bit windows 7 javaw access is denied [issue](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/559012/)
4. Windows 7 Access is denied permission ownership [issue](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-access-denied-permission-ownership/)

Comment: have you tried 'run as administrator'?

Comment: You can try running Eclipse as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=559997&S=a4836b4add35f1ac144df946cb1ef64d) and define explicitly the vm path in your `eclipse.ini` (like [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659)).

```
-vm
C:/Prog/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

(adapt the path and the Java version number).

This should solve the issue.

Comment: I reinstalled jdk 1.6, 764 bit as administrator. I think I did that the first time when everything worked. If I remember right things started hosing up when I added GWT to eclipse, but I was upgrading the jdk to a later version, so I may be mistaken. I changed the eclipse.ini as well, but it's still showing the same error. I've been working with eclipse for years and I've never seen this problem before. Anything else I could try????

Comment: @james: try adding the vm parameter as indicated in the answer to a fresh eclipse installation, then try to add GWT, and see if you reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of security restrictions in Windows7. One of them is, it does not allow applications to write data in system directories. The easiest solution I find is to move Eclipse and workspace to a drive other `C:\` drive. But that may not fit for everyone.

You may want to look into this: [Eclipse and Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872479/eclipse-and-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following lines in my eclipse.ini file:

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/bin/javaw.exe

And restarted eclipse. This resolved my issue.
Make sure to add these lines before "-vmargs" argument in eclipse.ini file.
Also make sure to edit the path for javaw.exe as per your local set up.