# Eclipse crashes at startup; Exit code=13 

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6, exit-code

I am trying to work with Eclipse Helios on my x64 machine (Im pretty sure now that this problem could occur with any eclipse)  but it just doesn't cooperate.

When I try to run eclipse I get the following:
[image: exit code=13]

I have installed

- Helios EE x64 (latest version)
- JDK 1.6.025 (x64)

I have linked my Environment Variables up correctly and tried to compile a Java file through `cmd` and have succeeded.

Whenever I tried running eclipse i get `exit code=13 (required java version=1.5)`

**I tried running the following in cmd:**
`-vm "mypath\jdk1.6.025\jre\bin"`
command as forums suggested

as well as other paths
`-vm "mypath\jdk1.6.025\bin"`
`-vm "mypath\jdk1.6.025\jre\bin\javaw.exe"`
even
`-vm "mypath\jre6\bin"` out of desperation
to no avail.

---

I am all out of ideas and I wonder if anybody had this problem. I even downloaded the helios x86 version and x86 JDK version yet it did not fix the problem. (I changed the environment variables) 
I changed everything back but I'm stuck...

**Related Question:** [Cannot Run Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: Is java on the path? What is the exact output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that a directory had an `!` in its name and eclipse had a problem with that.

Once I switched the directory (from Desktop which is located in the user directory which had `!` in it to C:/ ) everything worked fine. (look at the Djava.class.path in the image located in my the question above for the whole path - it should make it clear what the problem was)

Vista allows you to create a username that contains `!` character and then a lot of programs have issues with it

**Update**

If somebody is still getting this problem even though their path is ok I suggest

- trying to look at the Environment Variables
- then try uninstalling  the Helios EE ( or any other version of ee you are running ) and JDK and then reinstalling the 86x versions of both (they should still work on the 64x platform).
- for further explanation look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Thank you everybody that tried to help

Comment: Yes that is a bit odd, not liking ! in a directory name.

Comment: Had the same problem and removing the "!" in the folder name worked.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check that your have downloaded the x64 version. ;)

And your installed Java, is x86. Use Eclipse x86 if you use Java x86.

Comment: my question states: I have installed

*   Helios EE x64 (latest version)
*   JDK 1.6.025 (x64)
Also I allready figured out what is wrong and answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Because your eclipse's env-arch was not matched with java-arch, for instance: eclipse-64bit run in java-32bit or vice versa.

In Windows: `Set correct env path to the specific 32 or 64bit java acording to eclipse.`

In Linux: 
  Try `run: [path-to-eclipse]/eclipse -vm [jdk-path]/bin`

Answer (score 1):

What version of java is on your path when you start eclipse? Try entering java -version on a command prompt. You will want Sun java 1.5 or higher. See http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html

Comment: Also if you're using a 64-bit Java, you should be sure you're using a 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: I also already fallowed the instructions from the link yet they did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a permissions error for me. I change the kepler folder, eclipse root directory to have permissions set to everyone all. This is going to be a security risk so I will need to set the permissions to be program specific. using procmon.exe I found that javaw.exe was getting write permissions denied. The programmers of eclipse and javaw.exe did not give those programs elevated permissions to run as trustedinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem

Turned out my Java version in the PATH had been updated to 1.8

Once I changed this back to 1.7, my Eclipse started without issues

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Little more explanation would help out the fellow programmers to understand why the solution worked out.