# Eclipse wont recognize Android support library revision 9

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently downloaded all the latest updates for my eclipse/Android plugins (before the upgrades everything worked fine). I got everything to work except when i try to create a new project I get a message that I need `Android support library revision 8`. I click Install/Upgrade and It proceeds to download and install the library. When it finishes the tiny download/install window disappears but the window which informs me that i need `Android support library revision 8` remains open and i cant click finish to create new project. I tried closing the window and eclipse and trying it again but it always leads me to the window which states I need the `Android support library revision 8`. I didnt move eclipse to any other location and I am wondering what is wrong.

I had a problem before with an `!` in my eclipse path and eclipse wouldnt work because of exit error 13. I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166795/eclipse-crushes-at-startup-exit-code-13) about it before. My answer explains what has happened and the easy fix.

I am wondering what is wrong now. Do i need to manually link the support library?
Im really frustrated because its taking me forever to set this up.

**Update:**
I tried restarting eclipse and reinstalling the library multiple times.

I upgraded the  android sdk tools and sdk platform-tools before i installed the support libraries.

Comment: I have compatibility folder on that path

Comment: Just rename that as support and restart once your eclipse. And, create new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like these similar issue i'd for 2 days ago. Whenever, i'm trying to create a new project its showing me like below

[image]

For, this i've downloaded that `support` library using `Install/Upgrade` and in my path `E:/Android/Android-Sdk/extras/android/compaitability` I've changed the name of `compaitability` as `support` and after just restarted my Eclipse. Its working fine.

Hope these helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Other then a small typo in Support which made me restart eclipse twice. Everything worked out great :D. Thank you for your help!! (the folder should be **support** not **Support**)

Comment: This issue posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859#makechanges). Its more than year passed, but it is not resolved. Very frustrating. For me, for android api 17 and support library rev.13, I copied `android-sdk\android-compatibility` folder to `android-sdk\extras\android` and renamed it `compatibility`, so it became `android-sdk\extras\android\compatibility`. It helps me.

Comment: Instead of copying anything, I made a symlink at `/extras/android/compatibility` to `/android-compatibility`. (`/extras/android> mklink /D compatibility ../../android-compatibility`)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating android sdk tools and sdk platform-tools and restart eclipse? ADT has dependencies on these.

Comment: There are no updates found I allready updated before installing the support libraries