# Eclipse run fail - Error code 13 and Failed to load JNI shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I'm having problems to run eclipse in my job - at my home desktop I got everything as a 64 bit version. What I did was copy the folders to my job desktop and it doesn't. I checked the architecture here and it's 64 bits too. The failure come from both sides:

If I set my virtual machine as:

C:\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

I receive the error from code 13.

If I set the virtual machine as

C:\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll

I receive the error from "Can't load shared library"

my source researches were :

1. [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)
2. [Eclipse reported "Failed to load JNI shared library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585135/eclipse-failed-to-load-jni-shared-library)
3. [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)
4. [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)
5. [Eclipse crashes at startup; Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166795/eclipse-crashes-at-startup-exit-code-13)

Resuming:

Home desktop - Windows 64, JRE 64, Eclipse Juno 64

Job desktop - Windows 64, JRE 64, Eclipse Juno 64

Anyone got any idea of what I could do? Cos with my research everything I tryed was in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the `Java Development Kit` JDK.
You probably only have the `JRE` installed. This has happened to me before and thats how I fixed it.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Could be the solution, at my home computer I have the JDK, I will check it out and feedback if it works, TY

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue. My reason is I have some other softwares(like oracle) includes some version of JVM, but don't have JNI. And the installation of that kind of software add something to my Path variable. Then eclipse search that path and failed.

Please examine your Path enviroment variable and see if exists any wrong path in front of the correct JVM path, or just try to move your JVM bin path in front of all the others.

Comment: I can't acess PATH cos of the security protocol but Colin was right - the JDK was lacking in my case, that worked here. But ty for the support.