# How do I get rid of this eclipse returned exit code = 13 error?

Tags: java

Can you tell me what is wrong with this?

[image: What did I do?!]

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166795/eclipse-crashes-at-startup-exit-code-13

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to go into (on Windows 8.1):

System > Advanced system setting > Environment Variables

Under 'System variables' in the 'Path' variable there was the following first:

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;

I removed this and Eclipse worked again!