# Eclipse Juno and the missing Android preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, preferences, adt

Ok I have installed the Android SDK rev 20.0.3, then installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, then used the install software link to install the Android ADT plugin from `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`.

When I go to set the preferences to show my SDK location, Android is missing.  I have removed and reloaded several times into different locations but have had no luck in getting this to work.

I'm running Windows 7 32 bit

Here is what I have tried:

- I Started Eclipse with "run as administrator" before installing the
  ADT plugin.
- I the reset perspective and reload of ADT but this also
  didn't have any effect.
- I tried different versions of eclipse, both
  classic and Java EE, Indigo and Juno releases.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try cleaning all the other eclipse locations when installing it fresh - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1874192/995891 lists some

Comment: Yeah I removed all folders I could find that referenced eclipse or android, including c:\users, even removed and reinstalled the SDK as well.

Comment: Use IntelliJ instead. :) That's my personal suggestion. All the Android tools are integrated -- no plugin necessary.