# How to change or specify the directory where the tmp***.instance file is written to by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've built and installed an Eclipse Plugin Java application to `Program Files` directory in Windows 7.

I have a problem starting the application.

It looks like whenever the application is started, Eclipse Framework tries to write a `tmpXXX.instance` into the `configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.manager` folder , and of course it does not have the permission to do that, so the program won't start. I've tried running the program as Admin, still have the same problem.

Ive tried out a couple of things, tried google for it,  and also still could not get Eclipse to write the instance variable somewhere else.

Thanks, any help is appreciate it :)

Comment: what OS are you using ? if vista or above then try to run eclipse as administrator

Comment: Thanks.Im running Windows 7, I've tried running it as Admin, still have the same problem....

Comment: where do you see the error ? what does it say ?

Comment: Main class in the application cannot be initialized. Copied the entire folder to another directory, and worked fine.

Comment: It's trying to write the tmpXXX.instance file into the configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.manager folder, but it doesnt have permission to write in Program Files directory. I have no idea how to specify another directory for Eclipse to write the instance file to.

Comment: I don't get it, is it an Eclipse problem or your java app problem? If it's in your java code, how do you specify your tmp folder in your code ?

Comment: It is an Eclipse problem. The application is written as a Eclipse PLugin, it gets activated by Eclipse runtime. The problem is that Eclipse runtime tries to write an instance file to the  configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.manager directory when it starts the application, it then runs into a permission problem if the files are installed in the program files directory.

Comment: I am not sure why you are seeing this problem because if a software tries to write to "Program Files" it is silently redirected to another directory. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872479/eclipse-and-windows-7

Comment: Btw what is the version of Eclipse that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change this setting in `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Your\Accessible\Temps\Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the eclipse.ini to point to [another configuration location](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html). Add this line

```
-configuration <writableLocationPath>
```