# Eclipse loses perpectives, view and last opened files

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse instance (newly installed SDK Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800) does not save perspective settings. Also the last opened files and views are not saved after closing.

Anybody know how to fix? (Currently running Win7)

Comment: Is your workspace located in a directory your user account has write permissions to? (For example, your user directory)

Comment: Yes under home/workspaces

Comment: You might try some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872479/eclipse-and-windows-7 I'm guessing it's still an issue with the security policies.